# Mean Value Property of Harmonic Functions from Cauchy's Integral Formula

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, cauchy-integral-formula

Okay. So, my confusion around harmonic functions as they are treated in Conway's stems from trying to properly interpret the following problem:

> Use the Cauchy integral formula to derive the mean value property of harmonic functions, that $$u(z_0) = \int_{0}^{2 \pi} u(z_0+\rho e^{i \theta}) d{\theta}$$ where $u(z)$ is harmonic in a domain $U$ and the closed disk $\{z : |z-z_0 | \le \rho \}$ is contained in $U$.

Here is where my confusion arises and why I think the above statement is slightly ambiguous:

[image]

[image]

The above comes from Conway's book on complex analysis. So, Conway offers a definition of a real-valued harmonic function and then states some facts about them. In particular, if $u$ is a harmonic function on a simply connected domain $G$, then there is another harmonic function $v$ on $G$ such that $f = u + iv$ is analytic on $G$. But in proposition 1.3 we are suddenly dealing with complex-valued harmonic functions, which, as far as I can tell, have not been defined. A consequence of proposition 1.3 is that these complex-valued harmonic functions are analytic. And in the proof they apparently have the same property as real-valued harmonic functions on simply connected domains--namely, that there is another complex-valued harmonic function on the same simply connected domain $v$ such that $f = u + iv$ is analytic.

Am I reading this correctly or is there an error in the book?

If I am understanding all this correctly, if we assume that the the above problem means for $u$ to be complex-valued, then proposition 1.3 states that $u$ is analytic and solving the problem is a very straightforward application of Cauchy's integral formula. But if $u$ is meant to be real-valued, then it's not as straightforward but still doable (just use the fact that $u$ has a harmonic conjugate $v$ such that $f = u + iv$ is analytic, and then apply Cauchy's integral formula to $f$).

So, what (if anything) am I misunderstanding?

Comment: complex harmonic functions are just $h=u_0+iu_1$ where $u_0,u_1$ are real harmonic; they are not necessarily complex analytic, only real analytic; if $u_0,u_1$ are conjugate then yes $h$ is complex analytic but not otherwise; the laplacian is $4\partial_z\partial_{\bar z}$, conjugate analytic functions are harmonic and others too (eg $z^2+\bar z=x^2-y^2+x+2ixy-iy$ which is neither analytic nor conjugate analytic); the mean value holds for complex harmonic functions but one can prove it for real harmonic functions only as the $d\theta$ measure is real so we can split into real and complex parts

Comment: @Conrad So, would you say that proposition 1.3 is a typo, that $u : G \to \Bbb{R}$ should be written; and that, in the above problem, $u$ should be thought of as a function from $U \to \Bbb{R}$?

Comment: @Conrad Also, what do you mean by "...the mean value holds for complex harmonic functions but one can prove it for real harmonic functions..." How can a statement like that be true but not provable?

Comment: I meant that it is enough to prove it for real functions as then you can prove it for complex ones just by separating it in real and imaginary parts (this holds because crucially the measure $d\theta$ is real so the separation carries through the integral);

Comment: in proposition 1.3 infinitely differentiable is meant in a real sense (eg partial derivatives exist in all orders) - I agree it is confusing somewhat but should be clearer from the context (as a "heuristic guiding principle" and regarded as functions in $x,y$ or equivalently $z, \bar z$, analytic functions are functions depending only of $z$, conjugate analytic only of $\bar z$ and harmonic can depend both on $z$ and $\bar z$ but separately like in $z^2+\bar z$ and not in $z\bar z$ which of course is not harmonic)

Comment: another way of thinking of harmonic complex functions is that locally they can be written (uniquely up to additive constants) as the sum of a complex analytic and a complex conjugate analytic function (and of course on simply connected domains the representation is global) and there is a fairly well developed theory of such that extends standard results from complex analysis like the argument principle, conformality (and anti comformality) etc